# How do you compute average growth rate?

Tags: probability

Suppose you have two possible yearly growth rates, r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> with respective probabilities of occurrence of p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub>. For example, if you start out with some quantity x and the growth rates for the next two years are r<sub>i</sub> and r<sub>j</sub> then at the end of two years, you will have r<sub>i</sub>r<sub>j</sub>x. What is the expected value of the growth rate?

The value p<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub> can't possibly be right.  For example if p<sub>1</sub>=p<sub>2</sub>= 1/2 and r<sub>1</sub>=3 and r<sub>2</sub> 1/4 then the preceding equation gives a value greater than 1, but the 1/4 growth rate should more than counterbalance the growth rate of 3 to give an overall growth rate less than 1.

This seems like a more reasonable approach.  At the end of n years, r<sub>1</sub> should occur p<sub>1</sub>n times and r<sub>2</sub> should occur p<sub>2</sub>n times.  The overall growth is then r<sub>1</sub><sup>p<sub>1</sub>n</sup> r<sub>2</sub><sup>p<sub>2</sub>n</sup>. It makes sense intuitively to take the expected growth rate to be the nth root of this, giving r<sub>1</sub><sup>p<sub>1</sub></sup> r<sub>2</sub><sup>p<sub>2</sub></sup>. For the example in the previous paragraph, this works out to .866, which agrees with the intuition that the rate should be less than 1.

I am surely not the first person to think of this.  Does what I say make sense?  How is it described in general probabilistic terms?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two possible yearly growth rates, then $p_1 + p_2 = 1$ and the growth rate over a period of $n$ years is given by the random variable $$Y = (1+r_1)^X (1+r_2)^{n-X},$$ where $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p_1)$$ is the number of years during this period where rate $r_1$ was observed.  Note here I have used the convention that $r_i > 0$ represents an increase from the previous year.  Therefore, we wish to evaluate $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{1+r_1}{1+r_2}\right)^X (1+r_2)^n\right] = (1+r_2)^n \operatorname{E}[t^X],$$ where $t = (1+r_1)/(1+r_2)$.  [Since the probability-generating function of $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is given by $$G_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^X] = (p_2 + p_1 t)^n,$$ it follows that $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = (1+r_2)^n \left( p_2 + p_1 \frac{1+r_1}{1+r_2} \right)^n = ((1+r_2) p_2 + (1+r_1) p_1)^n.$$
So for example, if $p_1 = 1/3$, $p_2 = 1 - 1/3 = 2/3$, $r_1 = 1/4$, and $r_2 = 1/10$, then for $n = 5$ years, we would have an expected five-year growth rate of $\frac{6436343}{3200000} \approx 2.01136$.  It is important to observe that the order in which the yearly rates are $r_1$ or $r_2$ is irrelevant; only the number of years which had each rate is important.

The following *Mathematica* code performs $10^6$ simulations:

```
G[p_, r1_, r2_, n_] := Times @@ RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1 + r1, 1 + r2}, n];

Mean @ ParallelTable[G[1/3, 1/4, 1/10, 5], 10^6]
```

The result I obtained was $2.0114$ which is consistent with the above calculation.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer, but I was unfortunately unable to follow. In your final equation, it appears you are saying that, using r instead of (1+r), that E(r^n)=E(r)^n, where E(r) = p1 r1 + p2 r2

Comment: @user1153980 The growth rates are not random variables.  The only thing that is random is the number of years each growth rate occurs in the $n$-year period.  As such, your equation does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I see where my thinking was off.  Assuming independence of variables, E(r<sub>1</sub>r<sub>2</sub>)=E(r<sub>1</sub>)E(r<sub>2</sub>)=E(r)<sup>2</sup>, where  E(r<sub>1</sub>)=E(r<sub>2</sub>) = E(r) = p<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> +  p<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub>.  The example that I gave is somewhat counter-intuitive, but it still holds that the expected growth rate in this case is greater than 1.